# User authentication from domain joined Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC on isolated network computer takes 2 or 3 minutes

Tags: windows-10, authentication

Machines of concern are on a VLAN isolated from external sites via firewall rule. These machines **can** communicate with the domain controllers. User authentication from Windows 10 Enterprise 2019 LTSC machines takes two or three minutes. Machines running 1709 and 1803 on the same VLAN do not exhibit the problem. The long authentication problem is observed on initial interactive login, remote desktop connection, and when using "Run as different user" to launch an application. After 2 or 3 minutes the logon succeeds.

Used packet capture to troubleshoot. Packet capture shows what I think is a perfectly normal kerberos exchange.  The domain controller grants a ticket to the workstation that appears to be valid for the authenticating user. Then the machine will query DNS for login.microsoftonline.com.  It will spend the next two or three minutes attempting to connect to addresses for this site which are intentionally blocked by a perimeter firewall. And finally, after 2 or 3 minutes, there is some RPC traffic between the workstation and the domain controller which seems to complete the logon.

I think we should be able to authenticate without external internet access. Is there a simple configuration option that I'm missing?

EDIT: Mapped login.microsoftonline.com to 127.0.0.1 in hosts file. Logon completes successfully and immediately! I wouldn't consider it a solution, just additional information.

Comment: Are the affected systems using an OEM image?

Comment: @Davidw no, sir - not OEM.  Installed from a bootable USB created from an installation ISO for Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC v1809.

Comment: Is this a hybrid joined system? An on-prem only domain joined system will never reach out to login.microsoftonline.com (consequently, hybrid does). Also, verify if this appears on 2004 as well because a similar bug was fixed in this release that is supposed to reduce the blocking time.

Comment: @Steve yes, I think it may be a hybrid environment. Does that mean authentication to local domain controllers is insufficient?  I will set up a test using v2004.

Comment: Hybrid is hybrid. It requires access to local DCs and AAD. The observed behavior is potentially a bug, but fundamentally a hybrid-joined device requires access to AAD. If you don't want it to access AAD you need to disable the hybrid state.

Answer (score 0):

Got a resolution through Microsoft support. Perhaps this will be of use to someone else someday.

Since these machines did have internet access when they were joined to the domain, they became joined with Azure AD. Once they were moved to the isolated network and could no longer reach the cloud, we observed the problem. To leave Azure AD but remain joined to the on-premises domain, use `dsregcmd /leave`. [Docs for dsregcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/troubleshoot-device-dsregcmd).